# Multiple instance in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have an api made in fastapi named "/get-data" which is using for scraping the data from a website using selenium chrome driver and it takes 5 minutes to return response back to the user. So if user A & B hits the "/get-data" api in parallel then it waits for user A to complete its requests then proceed to the user B request and so on. How can I fix this issue.

If its the selenium driver instance problem then how can I solve this problem

I have tried nothing but thinking of implement the multi-threading or multi-processing.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blocking the event loop, you can use `asyncio.to_thread()` to run the blocking call in a separate thread. This allows the event loop to continue processing other coroutines while waiting for the blocking call to complete.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from selenium import webdriver
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

async def get_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver

async def scrape_data(url):
    driver = await get_driver()
    data = await asyncio.to_thread(driver.get, url)
    return data

@app.get("/get-data")
async def handle_request(url: str, driver = Depends(get_driver)):
    data = await scrape_data(url)
    return {"data": data}
```

The `scrape_data()` function uses `asyncio.to_thread()` to run the blocking `driver.get()` call in a separate thread. The await keyword is used to wait for the thread to complete and return the result back to the coroutine.

This allows the event loop to continue processing other coroutines while the blocking call is running in a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I have used now threading to create new thread each time on each api requests. Its now taking very less time to complete the request.